# Java Newbie Calendar Class Questions

Tags: java

Need help understanding below test code.  Specifically I do not understand what the "11" and "12" represent in the calendar.set method?    example  "openCal.set(11, openHrs).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     {

         int openHrs = 07;
         int openMins = 30;
         int closedHrs = 23;
         int closedMins = 00;
         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         Calendar openCal = Calendar.getInstance();
         openCal.set(11, openHrs);
         openCal.set(12, openMins);
         Calendar closeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
         closeCal.set(11, closedHrs);
         closeCal.set(12, closedMins);
         if(openCal.before(cal) && closeCal.after(cal))
         {
           System.out.println("The Business is OPEN");

         } else
         {
            System.out.println("The Business is CLOSED");
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: Where did you even get that code from?

Comment: Tip: Avoid java.util.Calendar and .Date classes. They are notoriously troublesome. Use either java.time or Joda-Time. Joda-Time's DateTime class has "with" methods such as `withHourOfDay`.

Answer (score 4):

This is perfect example of why we should avoid [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).

Instead of `set(11` code should look like `set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`.
Instead of `set(12` code should look like `set(Calendar.MINUTE`.

If you take a look at documentation of [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class you will find few examples of how to use [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-) methods like

- `set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SEPTEMBER)`
- `set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30)`

By looking at [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Calendar.java?av=f) of Calendar class you will find many constants and their values. They can also be found at

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html

so you see that

- [Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) equals `11` -> [(click here to check)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
- [Calendar.MINUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MINUTE) equals `12` -> [(click here to check)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MINUTE)

Answer (score 1):

Just digging into Calendar source code those `magic numbers` are tied to the following fields

```
private static final String[] FIELD_NAME = {
    "ERA", "YEAR", "MONTH", "WEEK_OF_YEAR", "WEEK_OF_MONTH", "DAY_OF_MONTH",
    "DAY_OF_YEAR", "DAY_OF_WEEK", "DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH", "AM_PM", "HOUR",
    "HOUR_OF_DAY", "MINUTE", "SECOND", "MILLISECOND", "ZONE_OFFSET",
    "DST_OFFSET"
};
```

So in that case you can see that `11` is HOUR_OF_DAY and `12` is MINUTE

Comment: You can also find the values in the [Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.ALL_STYLES) section of the API documentation.

Comment: Thanks to all.  Appreciate the quick, clear answers.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you looking at this tutorial? In the set function for Calendar that has two parameters the first parameter is an index for where the data is and the second is the value to set. So from the code that would suggest that 11 is for Hours and 12 is for minutes. The documentation is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html . The numbers should be replaced with constants from the Calendar class to make this code more readable and self answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar`s `get` and `set` methods use integers as the first parameters, which indicate the field that should be retrieved respectively changed. This might seem strange, but `Calendar` is older than `Enum`s in Java (and considering all the other stupidities in Java's date related classes, this one is a minor one).

As others have pointed out, the **only** acceptable practice is to use the constants defined in Calendar (`HOUR_OF_DAY` etc.), but syntactically, a *[expletive removed]* programmer can use numerical literals too (or even expressions that result in an `int` value).

Comment: so I could do calendar.set("HOUR_OF_DAY".length(), 9); and oddly enough still change the Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY field..... interesting

Comment: No only that, you could even expect to see your code posted on www.thedailywtf.com as soon as some other programmer finds it.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
Boolean isOpenNow = 
    ( ! now.isBefore( LocalTime.of( 7 , 30 ) ) ) 
    && 
    now.isBefore( LocalTime.of( 23 , 00 ) ) 
    ;
```

## Details

The [Answer by Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24452468/642706) is correct and should be accepted.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

The Question and answers have outmoded code using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `LocalTime`

The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) classe represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

```
LocalTime opening = LocalTime.of( 7 , 30 );
LocalTime closing = LocalTime.of( 23 , 00 );
```

### Time zone

Determining the current time of day requires a time zone. For any given moment the time-of-day (and the date) vary around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( z );
```

### Comparing

We can compare the `LocalTime` objects with `compareTo`, `equals`, [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-), and [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-).

In this example code we use the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This approach is sensible and commonly used. Using this approach throughout all your code makes your logic easier to comprehend and makes errors less likely. So we ask “is the current moment the same or later than the start but also earlier than the stop?”. A more compact way to say the same thing is:

> Is now *not* earlier than start AND now *is* earlier than stop?

```
Boolean isOpenNow = ( ! now.isBefore( opening ) ) && now.isBefore( closing ) ;
```